# What will be best (for performance) transaction isolation level?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

There, are two types of queries that are executed in my app:

```
DELETE FROM tbl1 WHERE user_id = 1;
INSERT INTO tbl1 VALUES (...), (...), ...;
```

and

```
UPDATE tbl2 WHERE id = 1 SET ...;
DELETE FROM tbl3 WHERE tbl2_id = 1;
INSERT INTO tbl3 VALUES (...), (...), ...;
DELETE FROM tbl4 WHERE tbl2_id = 1;
INSERT INTO tbl4 VALUES (...), (...), ...;
```

The ORM that I am using automatically sets transaction isolation level to `REPEATABLE READ` and I was wondering if it is a right choice for best performance. My goal is to only execute all or nothing (from 2 transaction above) and I don't care about any reads...

So which isolation level will be best for best performance in my case?

Comment: Why are you worried about the performance in any given isolation level?   BTW, is your ORM prepared to retry every transaction that would be the victim of a serialization error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`READ COMMITTED` imposes fewer overheads as PostgreSQL does not have to do dependency tracking.

In practice the difference is likely to be minimal.

Isolation level should be selected based on correctness, not performance. It's not possible to determine whether `READ COMMITTED` is sufficient from the queries provided, but I don't see a strong reason to suspect it not to be.

There are almost certainly many other ways to improve performance before playing with things like isolation levels anyway.

Comment: If read-only access is enough, wouldn't `REPEATABLE READ READ ONLY` be even faster because then the connection does not need to be aware of recently finished transactions?